# How an I Put a sum in the localstorage?

Tags: javascript

I want to put the sum in my localStorage thanks to a function because, I have to work with the creation of function. When I put the total of my basket in my local storage, the nav changes number. So, when refreshing the page, the total is counted as one more article and I have an error on the html tag "nan".Can you explain to me what is wrong with my code ?

```js
    let totalityPrice = document.querySelector('.subtotal');
    let products = [];
    let Total = 0;

    function displayProduct() {
      if (localStorage.length > 0) {
        for (let key in localStorage) {
          let product = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
          document.querySelector('.cart span').textContent = localStorage.length;
          if (product) {
            products.push(key);
            cartTablebody.innerHTML += `

    <tr>
    <td>${product.title}</td>
    <td>${product.price / 100}</td> //price=API data//
    </tr> 

    `;
            Total += product.price / 100;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    displayProduct();

    function calculatePrice() {
      totalityPrice.innerText = Total;
      console.log(Total);
      //localstoragesetItem//
    }
    calculatePrice();
```

Comment: what's an example of product.price?

Comment: Probably your product.price is string with decimals and total returns NaN when you try to calculate

Comment: Instead of putting each product in a separate localStoage item, put them all in a single array, and store that as a single localStorage item.

Comment: You probably have something in localStorage that isn't a product, so it doesn't have a `price` property.

Comment: Try adding `console.log(product)` to your loop to see what you're doing.

Comment: @danronmoon I am working with an API and the price is a sum ( ex : "price": 49900,).

Comment: @Evren  YesI am working with an API ( ex : "price": 49900,).

Comment: @Barmar 
I will do the test.

Comment: @Barmar My products is displayed correctly. There remains my problem of the Total price, I must use localsoragesetIem without affecting the progress of the basket.

Comment: @Barmar  In terms of the syntax and the declaration of my function, is it well constructed?

Comment: @ninstudic It looks OK to me.

Comment: The fact that it counts 1 extra item seems to support my suspicion that localStorage contains something that isn't a cart item.

Comment: @Barmar
It works well, in terms of the number of articles of the navigation compared to the localStorage. I will continue to bring the total to local storage. Thank you.

Comment: @Barmar What I don't understand is that I managed to put the total in my local Storage but, the amount is counted as an additional article on the nav and especially when I refresh it returns me null  in the value ( in localStorgae) part but the key is total.

Comment: @Barmar, 
So I decided to put it in the sessionstorage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like there's something in `localStorage` that isn't a cart item. Check that each item has all the required properties before processing it.

And instead of using `localStoage.length` as the product count in `.cart span`, use `products.length`.

```js
let totalityPrice = document.querySelector('.subtotal');
    let products = [];
    let Total = 0;
    function displayProduct() {
      if (localStorage.length > 0) {
        for (let key in localStorage) {
          let product = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
          
          if (product && "title" in product && "price" in product) {
            products.push(key);
            cartTablebody.innerHTML += `

    <tr>
    <td>${product.title}</td>
    <td>${product.price / 100}</td> //price=API data//
    </tr> 

    `;
            Total += product.price / 100;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    displayProduct();

    function calculatePrice() {
      totalityPrice.innerText = Total;
      console.log(Total);
      document.querySelector('.cart span').textContent = products.length;;
    }
    calculatePrice();
```